# Word (noun) for something which isn't (anymore) what people seemed to believe

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a noun in a specific context. Cobra bites were believed to cause only neurotoxic effects in victims, but it is clear that their venom also contains cytotoxins, which lead to necrosis. 
Is there a noun I could use in a title such as: The cobra ______________.

Answer (score 1):

**unmasked**

According to Cambridge Dictionary

> **[unmask](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unmask)**
>
> to show the bad, and previously hidden, truth about someone or something

or

> **[revealed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reveal)**
>
> to make known or show something that is surprising or that was previously secret

Answer (score 0):

You could try *apocrypha* as a noun:  ***Cobra Apocrypha***.

The now-wrongheaded understandings are *apocryphal*:

> [***apocryphal***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apocryphal) - of doubtful authenticity

*Apocryphal* is a fairly common word.  *Apocrypha* is not, but it's what you get when you make the adjective a noun.